# Expand a div from center with background image

Tags: css, animation, background-image, transform, background-position

I'm having a problem that sounds quite simple but is freaking me out since days.

I would like to expand a div from it's center with a background image, that doesn't move.

When I add the background-position:center the image stays fixe who I want it to be, but is very shaky (probably because the center position has to be recalculated during the divs animation).

When I leave the background position where it is, the background image is moving with the div expanding.

So how can I expand the div from it's center, leaving the background image at it's original top left position?

That's what I've done so far:

```
   /* the div containing the background image */

    .slideTitle {
      position:absolute;
      width: 0;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: #FFF;
      z-index: 999;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform-origin: center;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-animation: revealText 2s;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
      //background-position: center; /* the image stays in the center, but is shaky */
     }

    @keyframes revealText {
        0% {
            width: 0%;
        }
        100% {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
```

The html

```
<div class="slideshowInner">
    <div class="slideTitle" style="background-image:url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg');">   
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried a solution with clip-path, but changed strategy as clip-path is not supported in Firefox (and I hoped for a smart and simple solution).

There is a jsfiddle to visualise the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/db94cdmL/36/

What am I overlooking?

Thanks for your help!
Cara

**Update:**

As this is looking like a Chrome-related issue I decided to work with two different solutions using `@-moz-document url-prefix() {}`for now.

```
    .slideTitle {
        position: absolute;
        -webkit-clip-path: inset(0px 50% 0px 50%);
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: 18%;
        margin-right: 18%;
        -webkit-animation: revealText 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.58, 0.32, 1) 0.8s;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        top: 46%;
        text-align: center; 
        background-image: transparent;          
        @-moz-document url-prefix() {
            width: 0%;
            height: 9%;
            margin: auto;
            -moz-animation: revealTextMoz 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.58, 0.32, 1) 0.8s;
            -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            background-size: auto 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            background-image: url(/imageurl.svg);
            img {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like this problem only appears on chrome.

Comment: Adding  .slideTitle { background-position: 50% 0;} made the image stay centered in safari / chrome / opera, but still a little shaky. The animation did not appear in Firefox (44) at all. (OS X)

Comment: I think the only way to stop it shaking is to add a little js - it shakes as during the time when there is an odd amount of pixels, chrome may shift the image slightly left or right to center it properly. To combat this, you need an inner div doing the opposite (but the inner div needs to start off the width of the screen) - here is my fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/kf3zjtgg/1/

Comment: I'm definitely going to try @Pete s solution. Makes sense for me. Until then I'm using prefixes to address the different browsers! Thanks for your comments!